# error in afAuth.authState.verifyPasswordResetCode() after I migrate project angular from 10 to 11

Tags: angular

error in afAuth.authState.verifyPasswordResetCode() after I migrate project angular  from 10 to 11. error shown as Property 'verifyPasswordResetCode' does not exist on type 'Observable'. How to solve this?

for migrating angularproject I update  "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5", and "firebase": "^7.24.0",

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this.authService.getAuth().verifyPasswordResetCode(this.actionCode)
            .then(email => {
                              this.actionCodeChecked = true;
                              this.showLoader = false;
            })

Comment: getAuth() { //  returns the auth API that AngularFireAuth wraps
   
    return this.afAuth.authState;
  }